# Why there is an extra object after redirect to the new URL with windows.location

Tags: javascript, android, wechat

I built a server with Python+Flask, and used 3rd party javascript SDK in my page, and this page will be open by WeChat. Here is the code snippet :

```
   document.querySelector('#scanQRCode1').onclick = function () {
       wx.scanQRCode({
         needResult: 1,
         desc: 'scanQRCode desc',
         success: function (res) {
        var newurl = "{{ url_for('ReturnStep1') }}" + "/" + res.resultStr;
        window.location.replace(newurl);
         }
       });
```

When openning the page on Android, it could redirect to the new page correctly. But it refreshes the window with the content of res.resultStr immediately.

When running the same code on iphone, it is correct.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: More information, Wechat has a demo page for all APIs. Comparing with it, the demo uses alert message to alert the scan result. But I use the scan result to generate the new href location. But the demo works correctly and does not show the new object for the scan result. I am confused about why this happens

Answer (score 0):

Well here are two things I found in the [WeChat API docs](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=JS_SDK_DOCUMENT#Scanning_a_QR_Code):

1. `needResult: 0, // 0 by default, with the scanning result processed by WeChat. The scanning result is directly returned if it is 1.`
2. > Web page which is opened via Scanning QR Code in WeChat Android client will be closed after calling the scanQRCode API with scanning result returns directly. (This problem has been confirmed by WeChat Team and will be fixed in Android V6.1.)

I hope this helps explain the issues you are facing.

Comment: Thanks. But the test WeChat app for me is 6.3.5. Therefore, I think this the issue addressed in the documentation should be fixed. On another side, I need to use the scan result as the info for next page. In this case, the needResult should be 1 for me.